# R: data table to vector transformation

Tags: r

I have a R datatable df like this:

```
a  b
1  3
3  6
5  7
6  4
7  8
```

I want to transfer it to a vector:

```
c(1,3,3,6,5,7,6,4,7,8)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- read.table(text = "a  b
                        1  3
                        3  6
                        5  7
                        6  4
                        7  8", header = T)
```

with your table `x` you can achieve this with:

```
c(apply(x, 1, c))
# [1] 1 3 3 6 5 7 6 4 7 8
```